# Selecting specific overlay for article

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I have a presentation with complicated overlays to show how information can be traced during the execution of a program on its control flow graph (see [there](https://pro.yannsalmon.fr/_media/enseignement/preuves.pdf), eg. slide 14).

Now I want to make an article version of it with beamerarticle (not a handout) and I want to typeset only the basic control flow graph without annotations, that is overlay number 1.

So I tried (see specification on first line)

```
\begin{frame}<beamer:1-|article:1>[fragile]
État concret de la machine~:
\begin{itemize}
\item ligne en cours d'exécution (contrôle)
\item valeur de chaque variable (environnement)
\end{itemize}

Exemple~: partant d'un environnement où \|x| vaut $2$.

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\begin{lstpython}[style=numbers]
if x >= 0 :
  va_x = x
else :
  va_x = -x
\end{lstpython}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.65\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[style=vertex, onslide=<3>{active}] (1) at (0, 0) {1};
\node[style=vertex, onslide=<4>{active}] (2) at (-1.5, -.75) {2};
\node[style=vertex] (4) at (1.5, -.75) {4};
\draw[->] (1) -- (2) node [pos=.3, above, sloped] {\scriptsize\|x >= 0|};
\draw[->] (1) -- (4) node [pos=.3, above, sloped] {\scriptsize$\neg$\|x >= 0|};
\coordinate (5) at (0, -1.5);
\coordinate (dest) at (0, -2.5);
\draw[dashed] (2)--(5);
\draw[dashed] (4) --(5);
\draw[->, dashed] (5) -- (dest);
\visible<2->{\node[above = 0pt of 1, floyd] {$\{\|x| = 2\}$};}
\visible<4->{\node[above = 0pt of 2, floyd] {$\{\|x| = 2\}$};}
\visible<5->{\node[left = 0pt of 5, floyd] {$\{\|x| = 2, \|va_x| = 2\}$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

But the resulting article still shows the graph with all annotation superimposed over each other. How can I achieve only typesetting what corresponds to overlay 1 ?

Since the above excerpt is not compilable, here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<beamer:1-|article:1>
Some text

\visible<2->{Should not appear in article mode.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround:

You can hide stuff from the article version using `\visible<2-|article:0>{...}`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<beamer:1-|article:1>
Some text

\visible<2-|article:0>{Should not appear in article mode.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks ; this helps. I am still hoping for a solution that does not involve fidgeting with the very numerous overlay specifications in my document but will accept this if that does not happen.